# Adding Linq method with column rename results to viewModel

Tags: c#, linq

I have no problems passing Linq query results to views via a viewmodel with or without a .Select() method as long as I am selecting only a single column. When I tried using the .Select() option with a renamed column like this:

```
var custodians = _custodian.Contacts
    .Where(c => !(c.personid.StartsWith("RMR") || c.personid.StartsWith("GMS")))
    .Select(c => new { c.contactid, name = c.lname + ", " + c.fname})
    .ToList();
```

it creates creates a `System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType1<int, string>>` type list

I have an existing viewModel that I am passing to my view:

```
public class AssetViewModel
{
    public string PsgcTagNumber { get; set; }
    public string[] AssetAttributes { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Asset Asset { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public string Custodian { get; set; }
    public ?????? AllContacts { get; set; }
}
```

What I cant figure out is the datatype to use for the AllContacts property of the viewModel.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define a class.

```
public class Contact {
    public int contactid {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

.Select(c => new Contact { contactid = c.contactid, name = c.lname + ", " + c.fname})

public Contact[] AllContacts { get; set; }
```

Or just leave the entity alone, without doing a `Select` method on your query, and use it in your viewmodel - you could add a `FormattedName` property or something like that to handle your name.

Comment: That's the part I was missing. I had defined the class already, just wasn't casting the select to that class. I was trying to cast it after the select. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous type result is exactly what your select is producing `new { c.contactid, name = c.lname + ", " + c.fname}` - a list of int<->string or a list of `{ int contactid, string name }`
If you want to use an existing Model, like your `AssetViewModel.AllContacts` you need to define its type first, as @Joe Enos stated and then update your query a little bit:

```
var vm = new AssetViewModel
{
   PsgcTagNumber =...,
   ...,
   Custodian =...,
   AllContacts = _custodian.Contacts
                 .Where(c => !(c.personid.StartsWith("RMR") || c.personid.StartsWith("GMS")))
                 .Select(c => new Contact { c.contactid, name = c.lname + ", " + c.fname})
                 .ToList(); 
}
```

So then you have it: your view model, initiated and ready to be passed forward